# RYB or RGB when designing for the web?

Tags: color, website-design, rgb

After reading [this article](https://www.threedeepmarketing.com/blog/color-conversion-science-clockwork-model), I started to question if I should be designing websites taking into account the RGB wheel instead of the RYB.

What wheel should I be using for color selection for website design?

Answer (score 3):

First off, be careful taking information from sites like the one you linked. It's a marketing site, which means it's trying to get as many views as it can, not necessarily providing great, researched information. The specific article you posted doesn't seem terrible, but it is also mostly just opinion.

To answer your question, you can design using whatever color wheel you feel like using. It really doesn't matter much. Ultimately it will automatically be converted to RGB in order to display it on the screen.

With that being said, the most common color types on the web are *hex* (a form of RGB), *RGB*, and *HSL* likely in that order.

Comment: Concerning the last sentence: "hex" is just a way to write RGB in a shorter way. The hex colour #FF00FF is masked with [RRGGBB] in order to resolve to R = 255, G = 0, B = 255. A colour should therefore not be described as "hex", as it is not a distinct colour model but just a representation of pure RGB. The distinction between the two does not make sense here.

Comment: I would argue that they are distinct color types based on the same color model

Comment: how do you define "colour type", apart from being the colour model?

Comment: As a web developer I think of it as a computer does: a way of input. Since hex and RGB are different forms of input, I think of them as different types. It's similar to how 1 and 1.0 are different types in many programming languages

Comment: the question is about choosing between RGB and RYB though, strongly implying a focus on colour models. Since hex is not a colour model, it has no place there. The sentence as it is now might create confusion with less experienced users; maybe put the hex remark in parentheses. Otherwise good answer, cheers!

Comment: Fair enough. I updated my answer to more accurately reflect that

Comment: thank you, I believe it adds to the answer. If I was to be nitpicky, it would rather be a way of writing RGB, and not a form of it (as this could be understood to mean "derivate" or "subset"). But I'm sure the current sentence gets the point across. Cheers :)

Comment: I am uncomfortable with the term "color types". Those are color notations. and specifically to write code, for example, CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to ask this, but Why did you use an RYB model in the first place?

An RYB model is a historical model, I must say an outdated one, previously used to understand pigment combinations.

And another thing. An RGB is not a color wheel, it is a color model. A modern color wheel has both, primary light colors and primary pigment colors. Both.
Basically has all the color spectrum. Probably not all the gamut of it but all the spectrum.

On a color wheel you chose the color, and then chose the components of it. Either RGB components or some pigment combination.

That pretty much is my response. There is no reason you should use RYB.